# Разбиение на массивы в быстрой сортировке (Python)

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка, быстрая-сортировка

Всем добрый вечер! Сейчас в школе проходим сортировки, в частности быструю сортировку.
Для удобства выбранный случайным образом элемент обозначу как `rand_el`.
Нам говорят, что при такой сортировке массив разбивается на **три** подмассива:

- массив с числами, равными `rand_el`,
- массив с числами, меньше `rand_el`,
- массив с числами, больше `rand_el`.

Так вот: у нас в ДЗ есть такой вопрос: "Почему в быстрой сортировке в общем случае нельзя сделать разбиение на **два** массива: `числа < rand_el` и `>= rand_el`?

При каком условии на массив, это все-таки можно делать?
Я гуглил, в википедии и многих других источниках написано, что так делать можно.
Но вопрос всё же задан так, как задан.

В связи с этим, знатоки, помогите пожалуйста, предположите, какие проблемы могут встретиться при разбиении массива именно на **два**. Спасибо!

Comment: Если в массиве все числа одинаковы, он будет разбит на два массива: пустой и весь оставшийся. При рекурсивном вызове не будет прогресса - размер массива не сократился. Ситуация повторится, вы получите бесконечную рекурсию.

Comment: В быстрой сортировке можно делить на два массива. Просто это требует правильной обработки всех необычных ситуаций.